# No redirect or canonical to HTTPS homepage from HTTP version

Tags: php, html, seo

I have a php site that I did an audit on via Semrush. I have this one error:

```
No redirect or canonical to HTTPS homepage from HTTP version
```

I added this just before my head closing tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mysite.health/"/>
```

But that did not work, what am I doing wrong?

This is what my .htaccess file looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^mydomain\.health$
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: As far as I know their message is a bit misleading in the way that they're expecting an automatic redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. Can't prove it though, just something I've read some time ago.

Answer (score -1):

Your canonical link should fix the problem.  It would put a canonical tag into your document that should satisfy SEMRush.  They have to recrawl your home page to see the tag, so it wouldn't surprise me if it took them days or weeks to note that the problem is resolved.

It looks like you are trying to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS but there are some problems with your `.htaccess` rules.

1. Your front controller rule (the one with `index.php`) should come *after* the redirect rule.   Any URL handled by your front controller would not redirect. (That is probably most of the URLs on your site.)
2. I would not making the following exception: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$`.  All user agents should get the redirect to HTTPS.